# PM2 Deploy, Where to set secrets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I'm using PM2 to deploy my node app using the following ecosystem.config.js code

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'api',
      script: './index.js',
      autorestart: true,
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    },
  ],
  deploy: {
    production: {
      user: 'root',
      host: ['xx.xxx.xxx.xxx'],
      ref: 'origin/master',
      ssh_options: 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no',
      repo: 'git@github.com:notflip/my-project.git',
      path: '/var/www',
      'post-deploy':
        'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production',
    },
  },
}
```

In my project I'm using dotenv, and a .env file to hold the secret token that I need to use on my server

- the ecosystem.config.js file is in my repository so I can't store the secrets there
- pm2 doesn't seem to have created a /shared folder on my server so I can't leave the .env file there.

**So, How do I share my server specific secrets with my server when I deploy using PM2?**

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the setup of your server, but you could use `post-setup` to run a script that creates the missing directories and copies the `.env` file located on your server to the correct location after cloning.